# jQuery change css/text dynamically

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

What I am doing wrong? 
 I want dynamically change text of the divs and add/delete css class to this divs. '
 There are couple divs with the same name but different ids

```
 <div class="mydiv" id="1">Text</div>
 <div class="mydiv" id="2">Text</div> 
 <div class="mydiv" id="3">Text</div> 

 <input type="hidden" name="myfield" id="myfield" value="myvalue" />
```

I am sending ajax post to Spring MVC controller and perfectly getting an answer (data) true or false. But as I see it generates at first all values $(".mydiv").attr("id") and after this success doesn't see this.id for change it dinamically. how can I fix this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('.mydiv'), function () {
        var code = $(".mydiv").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/mycontroller',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: $("#myfield").attr("value"),
                codeId: this.id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == false) {
                    $("#" + this.id).addClass("myNewClass");
                    $("#" + this.id).text("FirstText");
                } else {
                    $("#" + this.id).removeClass("myNewClass");
                    $("#" + this.id).text("SecondText");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

Looks like there are multiple problems, starting with the loop, execution context of the ajax success callback etc

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mydiv').each(function () {
        //use this.id to get the current elements id - $(".mydiv").attr("id") will give the id of first element with class mydiv
        var code = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/mycontroller',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: $("#myfield").attr("value"),
                codeId: this.id
            },
            success: $.proxy(function (data) {
                //inside the callback this was not pointing the element, here a proxy based soution is used
                //another solution is to assign var self = this; before the ajax request and then instead of this inside the function use self
                if (data == false) {
                    $(this).addClass("myNewClass");
                    $(this).text("FirstText");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("myNewClass");
                    $(this).text("SecondText");
                }
            }, this)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `.html()` instead of `.text()`